# Meteor and socket io

Tags: meteor, socket.io

I am a bit confused about how to use socket.io with Meteor. There is a package called socket-io-client. Is that the only package that I should use or socket-io is required for the client side?

Have anyone implemented a connection? I have managed to print out on the terminal a message that indicates that there is a connection on the server but I cannot print any output on the browser console. Instead I get a message about encoding `Uncaught TypeError: response.setEncoding is not a function`.

Does the connection is on the same port as my meteor server or must be running on different port?

Thanks very much.